# Is JSON parsing wrong?

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and XCode 4.2.

To parse JSON response, I'm using this JSON parser: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

I receive this JSON string from web service (**this is console log**):

```
2012-02-16 08:21:59.525 JReader[558:207] {"rules": [
{ "id_categoria": "3","categoria": "cat03" },{ "id_categoria": "2","categoria": "cat02" }
     ]
   }
```

JSON parser parses to a `NSArray` with these two elements (**this is console log**):

```
2012-02-16 08:22:04.910 JReader[558:207] {
    categoria = "cat03";
    "id_categoria" = 3;
}

2012-02-16 08:22:04.911 JReader[558:207] {
    categoria = "cat02";
    "id_categoria" = 2;
}
```

Objective-C code to parse is:

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX"]];

    NSData* response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // parse the JSON response into an object
    // Here we're using NSArray since we're parsing an array of JSON status objects
    NSLog(@"%@", json_string);
    NSDictionary* datos = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
    NSArray* data = [datos objectForKey:@"rules"];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

}
```

I expect a `NSDictionary` with these pairs:

```
  key           value
============  ============
categoria         cat03
id_categoria        3
```

**MY QUESTIONS:**

1. Is there any error on json string?
2. Why is it parsing this way?

**It is my first time parsing JSON, so I don't know if it is parsing well.**

Comment: Why is this not your expected output? What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I've updated my question with what I'm expecting. It is my first time json parsin so I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: Even with your update, I don't see what you think is wrong. The root object is the array, right?

Comment: The log at the top is what you are seeing? That _is_ a dictionary with the pairs you expect, though I'm not sure about the inconsistent quotes. Note that there is JSON parsing/creation built in to iOS now, with NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: I don't know if there is something wrong. I'm asking if there is something wrong because it is the first time I do JSON parsing.

Comment: @jrturton After JSON parsing I get a NSDictionary with key=rules and value = NSArray. This NSArray has two values that make me suspect that there is probably something wrong with JSON string. Because I think these two NSArray elements could be two NSDictionary with two pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that. It's an array of dictionaries inside a dictionary with the key `rules`. That's exactly what you got.

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

```
NSDictionary* datos = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSArray* data = [datos objectForKey:@"rules"];
for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [data objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

So you're logging the array INSIDE the main dictionary. You're properly getting the JSON parsed, you're just logging something else.

Comment: My problem was that `[data objectAtIndex:i]` is a NSDictionary and I didn't know that. So, when I see its log I thing this `[data objectAtIndex:i]` is a NSString. I'm sorry, it was my fault.